# How to download zip bundle uploaded in design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi Autodesk Forge team,

I have a question about Design Automation use APS, how can we download `zip bundle` of plugin after processs upload zip bundle completed ?

[image]

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the URL to download your bundle from the response of [GET appbundle](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/appbundles-id-GET/) endpoint.

Here's what it looks like:

```
{
    "package": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/YOURAPP/YOURBUNDLE/YOURALIAS?X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Security-Token=...&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=...&X-Amz-Date=...&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=...",
    "id": "YourNickname.SampleBundle+test",
    "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2024",
    "description": "Bundle Description",
    "version": 1
}
```